# Delayed_job claims database doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I've set up delayed_job and it works fine under development.

However, whenever I attempt to run the script under production and run

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
```

I get this:

```
/Users/simon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `initialize': FATAL:  database "myapp_production" does not exist (PG::Error)
```

It feels like I'm missing something really basic here (from what I gather it's looking for the production database on my local machine?), but I'm a bit stuck as to where to look and what might cause this problem.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is pretty much obvious - you are starting your dj in production env, so it tries to connect to the db that is described in the "production" section of `config/database.yml`. It seems that you haven't created this db yet.

To create this DB run in terminal

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Forgive my lack of knowledge, but I'm not sure I understand the meaning of the production DB in this context - the app is fully operational on Heroku, would this not mean that there is a production DB already and I'd just need to define the correct DB in database.yml, rather than creating a new one? Or are these two completely unrelated? Sorry again if this is obvious, just trying to make sure I fully understand what I'm doing!